# several events on swipe? kind of like scroll events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to find som js code that detects swipe events in a mobile browser.
I want to have several events while the user swipes and not just one event when the swipe has ended.
Kind of like when a user scrolls page and there are many scrolling events fired.

Anyone seen this?

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

Comment: "several events" – you probably want a run-time interval (f.ex animationFrame), that calculates position based on touch gestures. Please explain more detailed what problem you have and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no "swipe" event, you would probably want to listen to the `"touchend"` event and add event listeners to it.
However, for a comprehensive touch interface you will need a more complex solution, detecting what's going on, starting with `"touchstart"`, `"touchmove"` and ending with `"touchcancel"` and `"touchend"`, then checking their distances and so on.
So what you end up with is a listener to all of those events that remembers it's state and calculates distances, time and direction, then makes decisions based on those calculations.

Not an easy solution, I know.